# Can't start qtcreator

Tags: linux, qt, qtcreator

I'm trying to start `qtcreator`, but here is what i get:

```
$ qtcreator
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
QQuickWidget: Failed to make context current
QQuickWidget::resizeEvent() no OpenGL context
```

Manjaro Linux x64, Cinnamon DE, installed newest Qt libraries.
Another Qt applications working fine.